Failed to launch , because the scheme does not have a registered handler in nextjs supabase
I'm encountering an issue with my GitHub OAuth application where the redirect_uri in the authorization callback URL is being altered. Specifically, an extra "y" character is being added to the start of the URL when the authorization process is initiated, resulting in a "scheme does not have a registered handler" error. I've double-checked my code, GitHub OAuth settings, and URL encoding, but the issue persists. How can I troubleshoot and resolve this problem to ensure the callback URL is correctly formed and processed during the OAuth flow? Any advice or insights would be appreciated.
const handleLoginWithGithub = () => {
        supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
            provider: "github",
            options: {
                redirectTo: location.origin + "/auth/callback",
            },
        });
    };

I tried setting up a GitHub OAuth application for my project with the correct Authorization callback URL provided in the GitHub app settings. During the OAuth flow, I expected the redirect to occur smoothly, taking the user back to my specified callback URL after authentication. However, instead of the correct URL, an extra "y" character is being added to the start of the URL, which results in a "scheme does not have a registered handler" error. I was expecting the URL to be correctly formed and for the OAuth flow to complete without this error.
